# Preventing a user from adding a different fields when updating a document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to prevent a user from creating spam fields inside a document, fields that are different form that state of the original doc (after it has been created)
my current rules looks like the following :

```
//Create
allow create : if request.auth != null  
&& request.auth.uid == userId
&& request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(
  ['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt'])
 
allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId          

allow update : if request.auth.uid == userId 
&& request.auth.uid == userId
&& request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(
 ['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt']])
```

The idea here is in one instance I will want to update clients

```
  await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Data', userCredential.user.uid), {
    clients: //data,
  });
```

in other instance I want to updated verified Email.
while prevent a user from creating a filed like

```
await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Data', userCredential.user.uid), {
    shouldnotbecreated: //some spam,
});
```

In the Rules update chunk

if I use `hasOnly()` it is so strict that it need the whole payload to be the same. as in
`['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt']`.

If I use `hasAll()`  or `hasAny()` a spam filed gets created.

Comment: That sounds correct to me. As far as I can tell, every write operation you do should use `hasOnly(['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt'])` to ensure only those fields can exist in the documents.

Comment: what worked fro me was combining addected keys and has only. request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt'])

Comment: Good to heaar you got it working @stop-error. It could be helpful for others if you posted your final rules in an answer, and explained how they work where your previous tries had not.

Comment: the issue was that has only need the whole doc to be inject but if i want to make an update to single object that causes there problem and it error out .. i think request.resource.data.diff makes a shallow copy with changes made (kind of like context state in react) and inject the data.

Comment: hasOnly() will always fail if you make a singular doc update without referencing the rest of the doc,  (same example mentioned in my code it needs the whole doc for some reason and it can be achieved by using data.diff other wise I will have to copy and update the whole thing )

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my by using a combination of
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly()

```js
//Create
allow create : if request.auth != null  
&& request.auth.uid == userId
&& request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(
  ['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt'])
 
allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId          

allow update : if request.auth.uid == userId 
&& request.auth.uid == userId
&& request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(
 ['clients', 'verifiedEmail', 'accountStatus' ,'createdAt', 'endsAt']])
```